# remote rejected error wen deploying to heroku via GitHub

Tags: git, github, heroku

I am trying to push to Heroku but I am getting a `remote rejected` error. I cannot figure out how to fix this issue. The steps I've taken are:

1. `cd` into the project and added git: `git init`
2. Added to git:

   - `git status`
   - `git add -A`
   - `git commit -m "my commit"`
3. Went on GitHub and created a private repo called `cleantrees`
4. Pushed to origin master:

   - `git remote add origin https://github.com/pete555/cleantrees.git`
   - `git push -u origin master`
5. Logged into heroku
6. Did `pipenv lock`
7. Added a profile: `touch Procfile`
8. Added gunicorn to the profile: `web: gunicorn pages_project.wsgi --log-file -`
9. installed gunicorn in my virtual environment: `pipenv install gunicorn`
10. In setting.py set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`
11. Recommit the the changes to git: `git commit`
12. pushed to master: `git push -u origin master`
13. created a heroku app: `heroku create`
14. Because I have no static files i did: `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`
15. then tried to push to heroku: `git push heroku master`

but then I got the error:

```
To https://git.heroku.com/fierce-forest-09377.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fierce-forest-09377.git'
```

When I do a `git remote -v` i get the following:

```
(pages) bash-3.2$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fierce-forest-09377.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fierce-forest-09377.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/pete555/cleantrees.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/pete555/cleantrees.git (push)
```

I can't see where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Heroku repo both exists, and has had a commit already made to it. This happens, as an example, in Github if you checkmark the "create .gitignore or README.md" option when creating a repo.

If you don't care about any commits in the heroku remote, you can use force push to purposefully overwrite anything in the repo already (i.e. `git push -f heroku master`). Note - don't do this lightly. Always double and triple check that you are doing exactly what you want and need to do when force pushing..

If there are commits at Heroku with files that need to be merged, you can fetch/merge or pull from heroku and integrate those changes before pushing back up. In that case, remember to push the combined master branch back up to Github as well.

Comment: when i do `git push -f heroku master` i get the same error as before.